# How do I use PresentationCore in a WebAPI hosted on Azure?

Tags: wpf, azure

I have developed a "simple" testcase:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetImage")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
{
    try
    {
        int bmpX = 50;
        int bmpY = 50;
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Pen(Brushes.Green, 3), new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, bmpX, bmpY));
        dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2.0), new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), new System.Windows.Point(bmpX, bmpY));
        dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2.0), new System.Windows.Point(0, bmpY), new System.Windows.Point(bmpX, 0));
        dc.Close();
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(bmpX, bmpY, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ex.ToString());
        return message;
    }
}
```

This is a function inside my ASP.Net WebAPI project, as part of a Controller (ValuesController as it happens, so adding this to a default project should reproduce the problem easily enough).
If I deploy this to Azure and run it locally, then invoke both from Fiddler, the local one works as expected and returns a red X on a green background, but the Azure one returns a blank image.

If I use GDI (System.Drawing.Bitmap) then it works OK, even from Azure.  Unfortunately this isn't a solution; I'm porting an already-written application from desktop to an Azure API service and the PresentationCore code is extensive and would take too long to convert to GDI.

Edit: if anyone has a working Azure/Web API/PresentationCore application that I could pick through, that could be very helpful.

Comment: Can we just clarify what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: The goal of the Web Api application is to take a text description of an image as input, and produce that image as output.  The business logic to do this already exists in a WPF CAD application which I'm converting to run on Azure.  What I'm looking for is whatever I'm missing that means this code doesn't work on Azure, where "doesn't work" means no exceptions, no errors, everything builds, but a blank image is returned.  I have run the Web API in debug mode with all exceptions enabled using VS2015 Pro and nothing is thrown, which is what makes me think this should work.

Comment: Honestly I think you're going down a rabbithole / world of pain. You'd be better off amending the WPF CAD application to work standalone and return an image, start up that app from your Web API (I wouldn't know if this is even possible on Azure, but just in general) to get the image generated, and return that. Hosting WPF in Web API is just not a good idea.

Comment: I'd second what @RudiVisser has said. You're creating pain for yourself. Now, if you compare a blank image and one with content, you'll notice the blank one is smaller. Still, not a path to take if it can be avoided.

Comment: I don't reproduce. It works in azure for me: http://webapplication120171220014539.azurewebsites.net/api/image/get

Comment: That's interesting; are you running it as an App Service?

Comment: yes. VS 2017 latest version. PS: prepend the name of who you're talking to with '@' other he won't be noticed, I just happened to pass by this question again. PS2: I'll stop my app now if you saw it

Comment: @SimonMourier Could you send me your project so I can see what the differences are between that and what I've got?  Not sure how PM works on SO; perhaps I could email you via your website?

Comment: You can download it from here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsmmEDGvydk2i016N2z_-ii7TkuK (please tell we when it's done), I have included the binaries, but you'll have to fix the usual nuget mess if you want to recompile :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, investigating.

Comment: Make sure you're running at least on Basic SKU. Free and Shared are no go for System.Drawing stuff (sandbox restrictions).

Comment: @evilSnobu - good point (this is documented here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions), I run Standard, but OP says it works for GDI

Comment: GDI is a very large API surface, it's not all restricted, some stuff survived.

Comment: I wondered if it might be a restriction based on the fact that I'm using Free (company hasn't setup the Azure stuff yet and I personally have no need for a paid sub).  I'm surprised I'm not getting any exceptions.  Building a simple test image with System.Drawing's Bitmap and Graphics.FillRectangle works fine.

Comment: @evilSnobu - you should place an answer I guess

Comment: @SimonMourier and evilSnobu yes I would accept that; alternatively are you (Simon) able to set up a throwaway free account to check if your test program reproduces my problem in that scenario?  I won't be able to check on a paid sub until next year at least which means the bounty would expire.

Comment: I can't create resources in the azure portal for 2 days now, don't know why (on 2 different accounts). I'll try later.

Comment: It works in free plan too: http://webapplication120171224114718.azurewebsites.net/api/image/get